# Port block off suggestions

Tags: engine, ford, mercury, intake-manifold

1967 Mercury Cyclone 390 FE motor. I have an old Offenhauser Ford FE 390 intake manifold with two fours (aka: dual quad or 4x2 carb setup). It has a "Y" hole in the back of the intake. Is there anything I can use to block this hole off?

Comment: Hi and Welcome.  Your question is hard to understand - please edit it carefully paying attention to spelling and punctuation.

Comment: Mike65535 I don't really need to change it up Mike if you were a mechanic in the fifties and the sixties you'd already know what it is there's only two holes in the intake manifold that's a thermostat hole in the blow by hole

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! [Is this the manifold you're talking about?](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/4ZMAAOSwoBtW2Oy0/s-l1600.jpg)  I take it the hole you're talking about is on the unpictured side in this image?